# CGImage to MPSTexture or MPSImage

Tags: swift, metal, cgimage, metalkit

I have an CGImage which is constructed out of a CVPixelbuffer (ARGB). I want to convert that CGImage into a MTLTexture. I use:

```
  let texture: MTLTexture = try m_textureLoader.newTexture(with: cgImage, options: [MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB : NSNumber(value: true)] )
```

Later I want to use the texture in an MPSImage having 3 channels:

```
let sid   = MPSImageDescriptor(channelFormat: MPSImageFeatureChannelFormat.float16, width: 40, height: 40, featureChannels: 3)
preImage    = MPSTemporaryImage(commandBuffer:  commandBuffer, imageDescriptor: sid)
lanczos.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: texture!, destinationTexture: preImage.texture)
scale.encode  (commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceImage: preImage, destinationImage: srcImage)
```

Now my questions: 
How does textureLoader.newTexture(...) map the four ARGB channels to the 3 channels specified in the MPSImageDescriptor ? 
How can I ensure that the RGB components are used and not e.g. ARG ?
Is there a way to specify that channel mapping ?

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not construct the MTLTexture from the CVPixelBuffer directly? Is much quicker!

Do this once at the beginning of your program:

```
// declare this somewhere, so we can re-use it
var textureCache: CVMetalTextureCache?

// create the texture cache object
guard CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, device, nil, &textureCache) == kCVReturnSuccess else {
  print("Error: could not create a texture cache")
  return false
}
```

Do this once your have your CVPixelBuffer:

```
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

var texture: CVMetalTexture?
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache,
      pixelBuffer, nil, .bgra8Unorm, width, height, 0, &texture)

if let texture = texture {
  metalTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture)
}
```

Now `metalTexture` contains an MTLTexture object with the contents of the CVPixelBuffer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks much easier. However I need only a cropped part of the pixel buffer going into the texture. I know the ROI coordinates. Can your solution be extended to do that ? If so how ? Thanks

Comment: You could create an additional `MTLTexture` whose size is equal to the size of the ROI, then use a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to just copy that region from the texture you created from the pixel buffer. That will temporarily use more memory, but afterwards you can discard or reuse the first texture. There are alternative ways to do this with Core Image or Accelerate, but to the best of my knowledge, they will all entail additional allocations and copies.

Comment: An alternative that does not involve making copies is to convert the full pixel buffer to a texture and then specify a clipRect and offset to the MPS kernel you're calling (or if you're using the Lanczos scale, set a transform on it). This will make the MPS kernel work on a smaller portion of the image. (However, if your crop region is very small relative to the source image, then doing a copy like @warrenm suggested might be more efficient.)

Comment: My ROIs are in the order of 40px...80px whereas my image is 960x540, so making copies might me more efficient. However (back to my original question) I still struggle with the channel ordering. My CNN assumes RGB ordering, but my Pixelbuffer seems to deliver BGRA and to make things even more complicated I go from Pixelbuffer -> CGImage -> Texture and then at latest then I don't know what the actual channel ordering is... Any suggestions ? If I put grayscale into each RGG buffer my CNN makes useful things, if I put color into it goes crazy...

Comment: The CGImage you can display on the screen, so you can see what the pixel order is there (if it shows up normal, it's RGB). For the texture you can print out its pixelFormat to see what the channel order is. You can also convert the texture back to a UIImage and display that. Example code here: https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/blob/master/TinyYOLO-NNGraph/TinyYOLO-NNGraph/UIImage%2BMTLTexture.swift

Comment: OK, the cgimage displays normal on the screen, seems to be RGB, however texture's pixel format outputs '80' which corresponds to bgra8Unorm. That might be the reason why the CNN does not work correctly. How to convert the texture pixel format ? I use m_textureLoader.newTexture(with: cgImage, options: [MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB : NSNumber(value: true)] ) to convert the cgimage to texture.

Comment: bgra8Unorm is not necessarily a problem. This means the pixels in the input texture are in BGRA order, but once they are in the MPS pipeline they are automatically converted to RGBA (you should be able to see this when you print the pixelFormat for the output MPSImage, it's probably 115). What this means is: if your model expects BGR input (because it is a Caffe model, for example) then you need to flip R and B (even though the texture says it is BGRA).

Comment: However... the problem can also be with the magnitude of the pixel values. The Unorm bit means that values 0 - 255 are converted to 0 - 1. If your model expects values in a different range (such as 0 - 255, or -128 to +128, or -1 to +1, or whatever) then you'll have to insert a compute kernel that scales the 0 - 1 range to whatever your model expects.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I already had a linear neuron in front of my processing queue to correct that. Your assumption that the pixelformat of the MPSImage being 115 was correct. So everything is OK in processing at the iOS side. However I had an error in my tensor flow script which I changed from gray to color. Now that everything is correct in training classification also works on the target device. Thanks again for your help, very appreciated.